# Stuck On How To Store User Input Into Class & Displaying It Into DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Fleet boatOne;
```

That's what I get when I run the code, why is it not letting me display boatOne?

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Boat Name");
            dt2.Columns.Add("License Number");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Maximum Load");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Fish Species");

            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { boatOne.GetboatName(),boatOne.GetboatLicense(),boatOne.GetmaximumLoad()});
```

Also, for the code below `MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetmaximumLoad();` I get the error message, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'"

```
 private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tempTextBox = BoatNameTextBox.Text;
            string licenseVariable = BoatLicenseTextBox.Text;
            int intVariable = Convert.ToInt32(MaximumLoadTextBox.Text);

            boatOne = new Fleet(tempTextBox, licenseVariable, intVariable);
            BoatNameTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetboatName();
            BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetboatLicense();
            MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetmaximumLoad();
        }
```

I'm trying to get the user to input their boat details and when the user hit's 'submit' it's stored in a growing list / fleet class, that can then be displayed in the DataGridView below. Once I figure out how to do that basic task, I'll be able to do everything else, I've researched so much and can't get a clear answer on how this done in windows forms.

Usually in console, the user input is stored in a variable using readline, and is easily displayed in a textbox

[image]

Heres the code for the fleet class

```
class Fleet
    {
        string boatName;
        string boatLicense;
        int maximumLoad;

        public Fleet()
        {
            boatName = "N/A";
            boatLicense = "";
            maximumLoad = 0;
        }

        //Constructor
        public Fleet(string name, string license, int maxLoad)
        {
            boatName = name;
            boatLicense = license;
            maximumLoad = maxLoad;
        }
        //Boat Name Method
        public string GetboatName()
        {
            return boatName;
        }
        //Boat License Method
        public string GetboatLicense()
        {
            return boatLicense;
        }
        //Boat Maximum Load Method
        public int GetmaximumLoad()
        {
            return maximumLoad;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you create `boatOne`?

Comment: It's in one of the code blocks above, `boatOne = new Fleet(tempTextBox, licenseVariable, intVariable);`

Comment: and where do you define it? Do you access it at any other place than what you show here?

Comment: I define it in the main form partial class `private Fleet boatOne;`

Comment: Are you sure to call `t2.Rows.Add(new object[] { boatOne.GetboatName(),boatOne.GetboatLicense(),boatOne.GetmaximumLoad()});` only after you construct `boatOne` in your button click handler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no im not sure,  I'm really confused on how I should be doing it, I've defined boatOne at the top, I've constructed it, using the textbox's the user provides, not sure why it's null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my code - I mistyped my button method, `private void BoatSubmitButton_Click` hours gone because of a typo haHAahhahaHAhahah time to slEEP

```
 private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tempTextBox = BoatNameTextBox.Text;
            string licenseVariable = BoatLicenseTextBox.Text;
            string intVariable = MaximumLoadTextBox.Text;

            boatOne = new Fleet(tempTextBox, licenseVariable, intVariable);
            BoatNameTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetboatName();
            BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetboatLicense();
            MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = boatOne.GetmaximumLoad();

            BoatNameTextBox.Text = "1";
            BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = "1";
            MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = "1";
        }
```